# Paypal Express Checkout Subscription using Credit Card Payment

Tags: paypal, credit-card, subscription, express-checkout

Question:

Is it possible to set up a subscription via Paypal api Express Checkout, so you can pay via Credit card and Paypal login. The Paypal login works no problem, but I can not get it to work with credit cards at the moment.

I have set the NVP SOLUTIONTYPE = Sole

I know you can set up a paypal subscription button, but the client want to sell a product (single payment or instalments) and add a subscription if user wants to sign up.

Many thanks for any help.

Llewellyn

---

UPDATE:

For anyone else who has this problem I got this response back from Paypal:

With subscriptions and Express Checkout, they will be PayPal only. Any time you specify a billing type in your SetExpressCheckout call, it turns it into a PayPal only transaction. The only way you would be able to set up a recurring payment via credit card (without a button) is to use the Website Payments Pro and Pro Recurring Payments. Website Payments Pro would allow the customer to enter their credit card directly on the website for one-time payments and also you can set it up to accept the credit card information for recurring payments. You wouldn't be able to turn that one-time payment into a recurring payment at a later time but if you wanted to set them both up at the start that's certainly possible. Also, you would be able to use reference transactions with your Pro payments as well.

Here is a link to the paypal [manual](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WPP_IntegrationGuide.pdf) for Paypal Pro.

Be warned, with Paypal Pro you can not accept American Express cards, if your paypal account is not American - which sadly is what I'm trying to do :(

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible with Express Checkout Recurring Payments.
You must purchase Direct Payment Recurring Payments (an addon to Website Payments Pro) in order to set up profiles direct via credit card.
Note that Direct Payment Recurring Payments is only available in the US, UK and Canada at the moment.

Comment: When you say "direct Payment Recurring Payments is only available in the US, UK and Canada at the moment," are you saying that the *customer* has to be in one of those countries, or just the *merchant*?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to make direct payment with Express Checkout,for this you have got create and account on paypal and please set only two options to working credit/debit card with Express Checkout.
solutiontype = Sole
landingpage = billing