# API differences between Paypal Express Checkout and Website Payment Standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm trying to understand the API differences between Paypal's Express Checkout and Website Payment Standard. I know the user-facing differences (Express Checkout forces you to have a Paypal account, while Website Payment Standard also processes credit cards), but I don't know the differences between how you can interface with them programmatically, specifically from a Rails app. Active Merchant says that it supports Express Checkout but doesn't mention Website Payment Standard. For recurring payments, I found [this](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring) gem, but it only mentions Express Checkout. How does it function (if at all) with Website Payment Standard?

I realize Paypal has multiple APIs, and that while Active Merchant communicates via Paypal's SOAP endpoints, you can also communicate via their URL-based API. I'm just getting confused because there is such an overload of documentation that it's difficult to understand what works with what.

EDIT - To clarify, what I mean by accepting credit cards is not forcing the user to have a Paypal account - having Paypal function solely as a credit card gateway (like AuthNet, for example). I know that credit cards can be tied to your Paypal account, and this is not what I am talking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than edit my previously edited answer, I'm going to try again.

Express Checkout was made to sit next to your existing payment solution as a "Pay with Paypal" option.  It has a more full API, and only requires your customers to leave your site to enter their payment information. There is a more detailed writeup [here](http://climbershaun.blogspot.com/2012/01/paypal-website-payments-standard-vs.html)

For clarification, YES, both Paypal's Express Checkout and Website Payment Standard allow you to accept payments from "Guest Accounts" (Customers without paypal accounts.)

I agree that the documentation is sometimes confusing.  Since you mention Rails, here is how to enable "Guest Accounts" in Express Checkout with Active Merchant.

I believe express checkout is only available for business acccounts (not personal).  If you have a business account, you will find a setting in your paypal profile - `Profile>My selling tools>Selling Online>Website preferences` Scroll down to `PayPal Account Optional` and select the `On` radio button.

**Edit:** Apparently this option can be found under `Profile>Website Payment Preferences>Paypal Account Optional`

Then using Active Merchant, call paypal with the `allow_guest_checkout` (This code is based on the [railscast on express checkout](http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout) episode)

```
response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(current_cart.build_order.price_in_cents,
  :ip                => request.remote_ip,
  :return_url        => new_order_url,
  :cancel_return_url => products_url,
  :allow_guest_checkout => true

)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So right now, I have dual implementations - one with Express Checkout using ActiveMerchant, and one with WPS using standard URL params. The merchant sandbox account that I'm using does have `Paypal Account Optional` enabled, and yet when I go to checkout in Express Checkout, it only gives me the option of creating a new account (but still providing a credit card) if I don't already have one. WPS, on the other hand, actually allows me to checkout without a Paypal account. I am passing `:allow_guest_checkout => true` with ActiveMerchant.

Comment: Sounds like that setup should work.  Does your paypal sandbox homepage list you as "Account Type: Business | Status Verified"?

Comment: Figured out the problem. We were using a version of Active Merchant that was so old it didn't support :allow_guest_checkout. I patched it with the relevant code and all is well now, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Both Website Payment Standard (WPS) & Express Checkout WILL accept credit cards. Express Checkout has more features (e.g. a return POST) and now both allow credit card usage directly, so the differences are smaller.

There is a setting in your paypal profile, probably under `Profile=>My selling preferences=>Selling Online` section that has the return and custom landing page options.

For a sole gateway function, you need to have Website Payments Pro and/or other form of solution that allows you to do a direct POST, which might include other hurdles like PCI compliance etc.

As for activemerchant, check out the Railscast series on paypal (specifically [express checkout](http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout))

The videos are a bit old, but I set up a payment solution using activemerchant and paypal express based off those videos just last year.  Should work for you

Comment: Also, it looks like express checkout does NOT accept credit cards for Recurring Payments.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992244/paypal-express-checkout-subscription-using-credit-card-payment Good luck!

Comment: If it does accept credit cards then what is the difference between it and Website Payments Standard? The way I understood it is that Express Checkout is meant as an alternative if your website already has a mechanism for charging credit cards, and you just want to add functionality to checkout with a Paypal account.

Comment: Website Payments Standard is not an API. It's a <form> with hidden inputs. Express Checkout is fully API-based. Additionally, with WPS the payment is completed *while the buyer is on the PayPal site*. With Express Checkout, it's completed after you call the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API.

Comment: As for Express Checkout not accepting card payments directly; yes, it does. You must pass SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in your SetExpressCheckout API call for this to work (and optionally LANDINGPAGE=Billing), and in addition, 'PayPal Account Optional'  must be enabled within the 'Profile' of your PayPal account.

Comment: In fact, forcing the actual landing page on which the user lands, is something you *can't* do with Website Payments Standard, and *can* do with Express Checkout. SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing will *always* show the credit card form initially. With Website Payments Standard, it depends if there are prior paypal.com cookies. If PayPal detects prior PayPal login cookies, it'll show the login form instead.

Comment: I think the answer can be further clarified to include this discussion. On its own, it seems to say Website Payment Standard cannot be used with credit cards, which is misleading. WPS and express checkout both sends you to a Paypal page and both allows you to use credit cards to finish the payment.